Wifi Extender using connected device's IP instead of assigned static IP
I have 2 Router .

Router 1 as Access Point (Wifi A)
Router 2 as Wifi Extender (Wifi B)

Router 1 is 192.168.1.1
Router 2 connected to Wifi A and assigned static IP 192.168.1.249
When I accessed both of them using browser, I can login on each user panel using assigned IP.
User panel Router 1 not showing Router 2 assigned IP.
Instead Router 1 are showing Router 2 using  one of IP device that connected to Wifi B.
it's causing IP conflict.
I can fix the conflict by disconnecting device with same IP, but Router 1 showing that Router 2 using different IP again.
How do i fix this?
My router is Archer C54
Router 1 IP list
Router 2 static IP setting
Device connected to Wifi B

In this instance, the static IP needs to be assigned on Router 1, allocated via DHCP to Router 2. Normally when doing a WiFi extender, isn't the extender supposed to have an IP Subnet that isn't within the IP Subnet of Router 1 (clients would still receive their IPs from Router 1)?

no, Router 2 using same IP pool as Router 1 if Router 2 DHCP setting disabled.

Has the WiFi extender functionality worked with Router 2 being in the same pool? Normally when doing WiFi extenders, the extender uses a different IP subnet, e.g. 192.168.2.1/24 instead of 192.168.1.1/24 (WiFi clients would still keep their Router 1 IPs)
